Mediasource sourcebuffer error when loading older blobs from a Mediarecorder
Mediasource sourcebuffer error when loading older blobs
The problem: I am not able to go back in a video recording by loading old blobs in a sourceBuffer
I am creating a js video player that records live the video from the webcam and allows to go back. The video could be very long (more than one hour). The idea is making a Camera Assisted Video application (like the soccer/judo one, to replay older actions).
Since the MediaSource sourceBuffer has a limited duration, I am using IndexDb to store and retrieve the various Blobs, which are pieces of video recorded.
Currently this is what I am doing to show the live video:

start the recording with a MediaRecorder. When a new Blob is available, store it in the IndexDB

I create from Javascript the video tag (more on why later), create a MediaSource, attach it on the video element and create a source buffer, then start retrieving blobs

I have a global variable i that tells me the id of the next blob to retrieve. Every time a blob is attached to the sourceBuffer, I fetch the next one and append it to the same sourceBuffer.


This works nicely, as I am able to see the livestream of the recording and retrieve all the blobs to save the total video (while using just the sourceBuffer, I cannot have a video longer than 150MB before it gets cut).
I have various methods to let the user decide to go back at what timestamp (keyboard shortcuts, custom timeline) and a function that, given a timestamp, returns me the index of the nearest previous blob.
My problem is, once I know what old blob to load next, I am not able to show it, since the stream just freezes and/or returns error.
Here is what I have tried so far, and none of them works:

Simpy setting the global variable i to the old blob id, so that the next loaded blob in the source buffer is an old one
create a new sourcebuffer, and start appending old blobs to it
create a new mediasource, linking it to the video tag, and using it
create a new video html tag, and start again by loading old blobs

Every time, when the first blob is added the sourceBuffer gets an error (which is not printed anywhere, since it returns an event) and the video freezes. How can I do what I want to do?
Here are the relevant pieces of code, you can find the full code here if it is helpful. Thank you very much
/** The blob lenght from a MediaRecorder in milliseconds. It decides also when a new blob is stored / retrieved */
const REFRESHRATE = 1 * 1000;
/** how much to wait from recording to showing the first blob of the live. Total delay to the live is this times REFRESHRATE */
const DELAY_MULTIPLIER = 2;
const mimeType = 'video/webm; codecs="vp8, opus"';
const videoContainer = document.querySelector(".video-container");

getWebcamStream();

/** get the webcam stream, save it to the mediaStream and start the mediaRecorder */
function getWebcamStream() {
  navigator.mediaDevices
    .getUserMedia({
      audio: useAudio,
      video: { width: 1920, height: 1080 },
      facingMode: { exact: "enviroment" },
    })
    .then((stream) => {
      // todo we can add multiple videotracks in the future
      const videoTrack = stream.getVideoTracks()[0];
      /** holder of the webcam audio and video stream */
      const mediaStream = new MediaStream();
      mediaStream.addTrack(videoTrack);
      if (useAudio) {
        const audioTrack = stream.getAudioTracks()[0];
        mediaStream.addTrack(audioTrack);
      }

      /** saves the webcam stream to various Blobs */
      const mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(
        mediaStream,
        useAudio
          ? {
              audioBitsPerSecond: 128000,
              videoBitsPerSecond: videoBitsPerSecond,
            }
          : { videoBitsPerSecond: videoBitsPerSecond }
      );

      mediaRecorder.start(REFRESHRATE);

      // * when data is aviable to the recorder, add it to the arrayOfBlob and then call appendToSourceBuffer to process it
      mediaRecorder.addEventListener("dataavailable", (e) => {
        const blob = e.data;
        storeBlob(blob);
      });

      setTimeout(appendToSourceBuffer, REFRESHRATE * DELAY_MULTIPLIER);
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log(err);
      alert(
        "Assicurati che la webcam non sia usata da qualche altro programma, poi ricarica il CARE system"
      );
    });
}

/** source for the video tag @type {MediaSource} */
let mediaSource;
/** buffer to hold various Blobs @type {SourceBuffer} */
let sourceBuffer;
/** index of the last blob added in the db. Autoindexing starts at 1 */
let i = 1;
/** @type {HTMLVideoElement} */
let video;

createVideoElement();

function createVideoElement() {
  if (video) {
    try {
      console.log("Removing previous video element");
      mediaSource.removeSourceBuffer(sourceBuffer);
      sourceBuffer = null;
      mediaSource.endOfStream();
      mediaSource = null;
      videoContainer.removeChild(video);
    } catch (e) {
      console.error("Error removing previous video element:", e);
    }
  }
  console.log("Creating video element");
  video = videoContainer.appendChild(document.createElement("video"));
  addVideoEvents();
  createMediaSource();
  setTimeout(() => video.play().catch(console.error), REFRESHRATE);
}

function createMediaSource() {
  console.log("Creating mediaSource");
  mediaSource = new MediaSource();

  const url = URL.createObjectURL(mediaSource);
  video.src = url;

  // * when mediaSource is ready, create the sourceBuffer
  mediaSource.addEventListener("sourceopen", createSourceBuffer);
}

function createSourceBuffer() {
  console.log("Creating sourceBuffer with mimeType:", mimeType);
  sourceBuffer = mediaSource.addSourceBuffer(mimeType);
  sourceBuffer.mode = "segments";
  // * when the previous blob has been appended, append a new one
  sourceBuffer.addEventListener("updateend", () =>
    setTimeout(appendToSourceBuffer, REFRESHRATE)
  );
  sourceBuffer.addEventListener("error", (e) => {
    console.error("Error with sourceBuffer:", e);
  });
}

/** add to the sourceBuffer the new segment */
function appendToSourceBuffer() {
  if (!mediaSource) return;
  if (mediaSource.readyState !== "open") return;
  if (!sourceBuffer) return;
  if (sourceBuffer.updating) return;

  getBlobById(
    i,
    (blob, timestamp) => {
      i++;
      blob
        .arrayBuffer()
        .then((arrayBuffer) => {
          sourceBuffer.appendBuffer(arrayBuffer);
          currentTimestamp = timestamp;
          updateTotalTime();
        })
        .catch((e) =>
          console.error("Error appending blob to sourceBuffer:", e)
        );
    },
    () => setTimeout(appendToSourceBuffer, REFRESHRATE)
  );
}

function moveToTimestamp(timestamp) {
  if (timestamp > lastTimestamp) return returnLive();
  if (timestamp < startTimestamp) timestamp = startTimestamp;

  getNearestBlobByTimestamp(timestamp, (blob, timestamp, id) => {
    i = id;
    createVideoElement();
    setTimeout(appendToSourceBuffer, REFRESHRATE * DELAY_MULTIPLIER);
  });
}

function returnLive() {
  moveToTimestamp(lastTimestamp - REFRESHRATE * DELAY_MULTIPLIER);
}

EDIT:
Following the advice of VC.One,  I tried to just load the single blob requested in a different video tag and see if I could play it. Surprise, I cannot. So now the question is, how can I store the blobs from a mediarecorder so that they are indipendent from one another and I can load them indipendently?
New code that shows what happens:
function moveToTimestamp(timestamp) {
  if (timestamp > lastTimestamp) return returnLive();
  if (timestamp < startTimestamp) timestamp = startTimestamp;

  getNearestBlobByTimestamp(timestamp, (blob, timestamp, id) => {
    // i = id;
    // createVideoElement();
    // setTimeout(appendToSourceBuffer, REFRESHRATE);

    console.log("creating new video element");
    const video = videoContainer.appendChild(document.createElement("video"));
    const mediaSource = new MediaSource();
    const url = URL.createObjectURL(mediaSource);
    video.src = url;

    console.log(blob);

    // * when mediaSource is ready, create the sourceBuffer
    mediaSource.addEventListener("sourceopen", () => {
      const sourceBuffer = mediaSource.addSourceBuffer(mimeType);
      sourceBuffer.mode = "segments";
      blob.arrayBuffer().then((arrayBuffer) => {
        console.log(arrayBuffer);
        sourceBuffer.appendBuffer(arrayBuffer);
      });
      // * only works if it is the first blob
      setTimeout(() => video.play().catch(console.error), 1000);
      setTimeout(() => videoContainer.removeChild(video), 10000);
    });
  });
}


(1) What's wrong with uploading files to a server (some folder) and then, only storing the video path (text) in the in database? Your video size will then not be limited to 150mb anymore. (2) Video playback must start on a keyframe, it's possible that dataavailable is containing sliced data so your "blob" might actually be the middle bytes of one frame (eg: they make no sense and make no picture on their own). PS What browser are you testing on? Could the mimetype be wrong? You'll have to read the bytes (check if keyframe exists) before sending them to the video player.

(1) can you explain better what you mean? the video should be continous since it's a livestream, but cannot be uploaded online because it would be used in contexts with very limited bandwidth. (2) ok, I should see if im able to save the different blobs individually (PS) both chrome and firefox
